# Application server for C programs?

Tags: monitoring, c, clustering

I'm writing some programs in C that will run in a distributed environment. Is there anything like an application server for C that provides clustering, monitoring, logging, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Application servers are more like a Java and Python and OOP thing. But surely there are "object request broker" models that are implemented in C, just can just add the libraries to your C program. You can provide us a little more details about your environment, I use Visual Studio on Windows and the clang compiler and gcc on Linux and SunOS. If you study the Q&A on various programming sites here, like [SO](http://www.stackoverflow.com) that are tagged C programming and application server you will broaden and deepen your knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

There are application servers for C, for example Enduro/X or Tuxedo. Each compiled executable operates as a "server" process which provides services. These platforms monitors them, reboots if crashed and provides load balancing features. Also middleware options are available.

Comment: Also Enduro/X provides Client Process Monitor. So that arbitrary processes can be registered in application. They are tagged and managed by their tags. I.e. start/stop/status and auto start with system boot.